# ¿Cómo identificar qué usuario realizó X acción?

Tags: base-de-datos, modelorelacional

Intento crear Roles y accesos de usuarios para diferentes acciones, las reglas de negocio que he declarado son:

Es un software para organizar proyectos, el software permite crear la representación de proyectos, dentro de los proyectos deben de existir obligatoriamente áreas de proyectos (por ejemplo, un proyecto de un spot publicitario, dentro de este proyecto puede estar el área de la creación del diseño visual del banner, en otra área puede estar la creación de la frase de propaganda, el otra área la creación de tarjetas para entregar a las personas, etc.), dentro de un área puede haber o no un grupo de tareas, es en caso de que se quiera dividir más las tareas que tenga una área, cada proyecto, área y grupo de tareas de área, pueden haber notas y recursos (imágenes, PDF, etc.). Lo que deseo es lo siguiente:

1. Un proyecto puede tener UNA o muchas áreas, y una área solo le pertenece a solo en un proyecto.
2. Un área puede tener CERO o muchos grupos de tareas de áreas, y un grupo de tareas de áreas solo le pertenece a una sola área.
3. Un proyecto, área o grupo de tareas de área puede tener de 0 a muchas notas, pero cero a muchas notas pueden estar solo en el proyecto, área o grupo de tareas de área al que les pertenece.
4. Un proyecto, área o grupo de tareas de área puede tener de 0 a muchas recursos, pero cero o  muchos recursos pueden estar solo en el proyecto, área o grupo de tareas de área al que les pertenece.
5. Un usuario puede tener un único ROL, pero muchos roles pueden estar en muchos usuarios.
6. Un rol puede tener muchos permisos y un permiso puede estar en muchos roles.
7. Existen dos tipos de roles, ROL_ADMIN y EMPLOYER_ROL, según estos roles:

   - Un ROL_ADMIN puede crear proyectos, áreas de un proyecto, grupo de tareas de una área, puede vincular un recurso para un proyecto, área de proyecto y a un grupo de tarea de área, además puede crear notas para proyectos, áreas de un proyecto y para un grupo de tareas de una área.
   - Un EMPLOYER_ROL SOLO puede crear grupos de tareas de áreas, notas para un grupo de tareas y recursos para un grupo de tareas.

     (¿Cómo puedo hacer todas estas relaciones que mencione en este punto 7?)
8. Los usuarios (ADMIN_ROL y EMPLOYER_ROL) pueden estar en muchos proyectos y un proyecto puede contener muchos usuarios, obviamente, esto implica que los usuarios que estén en un proyecto, se pueden sub dividir en áreas y grupos de tareas de áreas.

Ya tengo echo la gran mayoría de relaciones, pero me faltan la parte de los roles de usuarios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo los roles y permisos se relacionan a las otras entidades? ¿Cómo relaciono cada usuario con un rol a la entidad correspondiente?, no creo que tenga que hacer una relación para cada ROL, por que si tuviese 10, 20 o 50 roles, seria muy poco escalable relacionar cada una. Espero que puedan ayudarme.

Comment: No únicamente a **proyecto**, también a todas las entidades, ¿Cómo se que usuario esta en cada proyecto? ¿Cómo se que usuario creo una nota en cierto grupo de tarea de área? (si fue un administrador o un empleado, etc.), así sucesivamente (actualizare la imagen para ver si puedo hacer "más general" jaja)

Comment: ¿Cómo?, es decir, un EMPLOYER_ROL no puede crear **proyectos**, por ende, **no habría una relación entre usuarios y proyectos**, pero un usuario con ADMIN_ROL si puede crear proyectos, por ende, **¿Ahí si habría una relación entre usuarios y proyectos?** (me refiero a la cardinalidad), eso es lo que me enreda.

Comment: ¿Añado o no la relación?

Comment: tu pregunta es confusa... si un usuario puede crear un proyecto, entonces hay una relacion entre usuarios y proyectos. que el usuario sea empleado o administrador es una caracteristica que se mide a nivel del sistema, porque es una regla de negocio. Para la base de datos, un usuario puede dar de alta un proyecto... el otro control, lo hace tu sistema...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿consideras oportuno se pueda proponer una *posible respuesta* o es mejor esperar a que el OP haga correcciones a su pregunta?

Comment: @BetaM yo no termino de entender si lo que expongo es la duda de OP